# How do I create a query displaying only the rows with greatest and least values in Microsoft Access? 2010/2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, syntax-error, ms-access-2010

Here is where I'm at:
SELECT Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
FROM Client
ORDER BY Client.Balance DESC;

I would like to find a way to display only the Client with the Maximum Balance in the first row, and the Client with the Minimum Balance in the second. I've tried messing around with SQL commands, but I'm fairly new at it, so I'm not sure of the correct commands to input. So far I haven't come across a way of doing this, and nobody can give me a straight answer. I've uploaded the original data sheet, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/faip4bh7zdkh7ye/AAB50AWecEVwkYYCrf70SAkFa), and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/1r1vonijojm4qpu/AACaSQcatyE6_xW7ABV9kphMa) is what I want the end result to look like. If anyone has any suggestions or alternatives to offer, that would be great. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
(SELECT Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
 FROM Client
 ORDER BY Client.Balance DESC, Client.[Last Name]
) UNION ALL
(SELECT Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
 FROM Client
 ORDER BY Client.Balance ASC, Client.[Last Name]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the three approaches:

With WHERE subqueries (interchangeable with `DMax()`/`DMin()`):

```
SELECT Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance 
FROM Client 
WHERE Client.Balance 
   IN (SELECT Max(Client.Balance) FROM Client)
OR Client.Balance 
   IN (SELECT Min(Client.Balance) FROM Client)
ORDER BY Client.Balance DESC
```

With Group By HAVING subqueries (interchangeable with `DMax()`/`DMin()`):

```
SELECT Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
FROM Client
GROUP BY Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
HAVING Max(Client.Balance) 
   IN (SELECT Max(Client.Balance) FROM Client)    
OR Min(Client.Balance) 
   IN (SELECT Min(Client.Balance) FROM Client)
```

With Union and Top 1 clause:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
FROM Client
ORDER BY Client.Balance DESC)
UNION 
(SELECT TOP 1 Client.[First Name], Client.[Last Name], Client.Balance
FROM Client
ORDER BY Client.Balance ASC)
```